# preferences :configure user snippets for markdown doesn't work well

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot use any snippets in .md files except the

```
    "fraction":{
        "prefix": "/",
        "body": "\\frac{${1:1}}{$2}$0",
        "description": "use for latex"
    }
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, after googling a while, I have tried to findout the quicksuggestion property and set it as true, but I cannot find this property in any files.

```
{
    // Place your snippets for markdown here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and 
    // description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
    // $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the 
    // same ids are connected.
    // Example:
    // "Print to console": {
    //  "prefix": "log",
    //  "body": [
    //      "console.log('$1');",
    //      "$2"
    //  ],
    //  "description": "Log output to console"
    // }
    "limtforN":{
        "prefix": "limn",
        "body": "\\lim_{n\\to\\infty}{$1}$0",
        "description": ""
    },
    "limitforX":{
        "prefix": "limx",
        "body": "\\lim_{x\\to\\$1}{$2}$0",
        "description": ""

    },
    "sqrt":{
        "prefix": "sqrt",
        "body": "\\sqrt{$1}{$2}$0",
        "description": ""
    },
    "definite integral":{
        "prefix": "dint",
        "body": "\\int^{$1}_{$2}{$3}d$4~$0",
        "description": ""
    },
    "integral":{
        "prefix": "int",
        "body": "\\int{$3}d$4~$5",
        "description": ""
    },
    "definite integral":{
        "prefix": "dint",
        "body": "\\int^{$1}_{$2}{$3}d$4~$0",
        "description": ""
    },      
    "fraction":{
        "prefix": "/",
        "body": "\\frac{${1:1}}{$2}$0",
        "description": "use for latex"
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdyiz.png)

above is what I typed in the markdonw.json, I expected that will work as snippets, but it doesn't only the

```
    "fraction":{
        "prefix": "/",
        "body": "\\frac{${1:1}}{$2}$0",
        "description": "use for latex"
    }
```

works.
I don't know why , it just weired.

Answer (score 0):

add to settings.json

```
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "other": true,
      "comments": true,
      "strings": true,
    },
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

add to setting.json,also see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28048

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    }
```